# How to update custom option value of products from the cart page magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I want to add my two custom options and can change its value from the shopping cart page.
I added my two custom options (two Checkbox: Accidental Warranty and installation ) to all my products, I can edit them on the product page but in the shopping cart page, it's just listed. I want to add the two checkbox on the cart page.
an idea of how to do this, please?[image]

Comment: I need to do the same, have you found the solution yet? If yes the please share.

Comment: Were you able to find any solution? I have to do same thing

Comment: please brief your question with code add so depend on that  you will get an asnwer.

Comment: I tried to make this extension but it's left in mid and I used Mageplaza Extra fee extension ..if you required my code as well mageplaza extension then let me know

Comment: Is anyone able to find the solution for this? I am also looking for the same thing.

Comment: Any one found the solutin for this? Please share the solution